# How to obtain the address of an object referenced by an interface

Tags: go, pointers, types

I have two interface objects which I would like to compare against each other. I don't only want to compare if their values are the same, I also want to know whether these two interfaces are referencing the same object or if they're referencing two different objects with equal values.

Is there some way to extract the address an interface references from an interface object? Then I could just compare the two addresses to know whether the two interfaces reference the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two interfaces have pointer values, then you can simply compare them:

```
func cmp(v1, v2 interface{}) bool {
   return v1==v2
}

func  main() {
   a:=1
   b:=1
   c:=&a
   cmp(&a,&b) // false
   cmp(a, b) // true, compare values
   cmp(c, &a) // true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Be careful here.

Two different interface values can never "reference" the "same object" as an interface value always contains a *copy* of the value you wrap in the interface value. Variable *identity* (your "same object") would be "equal address" which is undefined for values wrapped in an interface value as these wrapped values are not addressable. So a clear no to your question.

But of course you can store a pointer to your value in the interface value *iff* the pointer type satisfies the interface.

It is best avoided to talk about "object" and "reference". Go has values of certain types. Some values are addressable. You can store addresses of addressable values in appropriately typed pointer variables.